# How to filter an object state variable in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, components

I have a state variable `stock_data` having an array of details of all stock. Structure:

```
    {
        "scrip_code": 506235,
        "short_name": "ALEMBICLTD",
        "Ex_date": "12 Sep 2022",
        "Purpose": "Dividend - Rs. - 1.8000",
        "RD_Date": "13 Sep 2022",
        "BCRD_FROM": "",
        "BCRD_TO": "",
        "ND_START_DATE": "06 Sep 2022",
        "ND_END_DATE": "12 Sep 2022",
        "payment_date": "",
        "exdate": "20220912",
        "long_name": "ALEMBIC LTD."
    },
```

I want to filter that data out. I need to add some new key value pairs too (`div_or_share` and `div_amount`).

My approach was to make a new array variable `myNewData` and mapping from state variable `stock_data`:

```
  const [stock_data, setStockData] = useState([]);

  var myNewData = [];

  const makeMyNewData = () => {

    console.log("in makeMyNewData with stock_data:", stock_data);

    stock_data.map((item) => {
      var [first, rest, end] = item.Purpose.split("-");
      var newObject = {
        short_name: item.short_name,
        long_name: item.long_name,
        div_or_share: first,
        Ex_date: item.Ex_date,
        div_amount: isNaN(Number(end))
          ? "-"
          : "Rs. " + Number(end).toFixed(2)
      };
      console.log("newObject:", newObject);
      myNewData.push(newObject);
    });
  }

  const fetch_BSE_Data = () => {
    console.log("fetching data");
    return fetch(
      "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/DefaultData/w?Fdate=20220912&Purposecode=P9&TDate=20221216&ddlcategorys=E&ddlindustrys=&scripcode=&segment=0&strSearch=S"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setStockData(data))
  };
```

I am fetching the data and storing in `stock_data` variable using `fetch_BSE_Data()`, but the `console.log` below shows that it's empty. So, while calling `makeMyNewData()`, `stock_data` is empty:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch_BSE_Data()
    console.log("after fetching stock_data:", stock_data);
    makeMyNewData();
    setStockData(myNewData);
  }, []);
```

I want to send this updated `stock_data` to a child component:

```
 <DividendCalendar stock_data={stock_data} />
```

How to resolve this?

Also, the `props.stock_data` has the original unfiltered data when logged in console, but when I try to initialize a state variable in `DividendCalendar`, the `div_cal_data` also turns out to be empty by the console log below:

In `DividendCalendar` component:

```
  var [div_cal_data, setDivCalData] = useState(props.stock_data);
  console.log("div_cal_data", div_cal_data);
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Not a solution to the answer but if you are not returning anything from map method it's better to choose forEach which does the same purpose of returning undefined .....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: @rgmt, I tried using that, but the problem was with the function using state variable. It helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Few pointer that could help

[move the function](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#moving-functions-inside-effects) inside useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {

     const fetch_BSE_Data = async () => {
           console.log("fetching data");
           return await fetch(
                 "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/DefaultData/w?Fdate=20220912&Purposecode=P9&TDate=20221216&ddlcategorys=E&ddlindustrys=&scripcode=&segment=0&strSearch=S"
           )
           .then((response) => response.json())
          // .then((data) => setStockData(data))
       };

     const async fetchData async () =>  {
       const response = await fetch_BSE_Data()
       const mappedItems = makeMyNewData(response);
       // this will replace the data,
       setStockData(mappedItems);
       // if you need to update/add to existing items then use map again
       setStockData(existing => {
          // logic to update existing items and insert new ones
          // [check React js new docs][1] 
       });
     }

     fetchData();
  
   }, []);
```

check React js [new docs to update, insert](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#replacing-items-in-an-array) items in array

// change the makeData

const makeMyNewData = (stock_data) => {

```
// console.log("in makeMyNewData with stock_data:", stock_data);

const mappedData = stock_data?.map((item) => {
  var [first, rest, end] = item.Purpose.split("-");
  
   const newObject = {
     ...item,
      div_amount: isNaN(Number(end))
        ? "-"
         : "Rs. " + Number(end).toFixed(2)
   }

   return newObject;
 
});

return mappedData
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It helped, thanks! It was closest to the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetch_BSE_Data` is making an asynchronous call to fetch data, but you're trying to log the data right after it synchronously. If you want to make this work, you can return a promise instead from your function and then await it in your `useEffect` hook like so:

```js
const fetch_BSE_Data = async () => {
    console.log("fetching data");
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setStockData(data);
    return data;
};
```

But another problem you'd face by trying to log the state right after the `setState` is that you'll only see the data after a re-render. i.e. When the component first renders, your `stock_data` variable is set to an empty array. When you fetch from the api and set the state, it will trigger a re-render of the component and will populate your state variable. But before this happens, your useEffect fn from the first render will complete execution. During this time, since it's still the first render, the `stock_data` variable will still be an empty array. If you want to view what the data, just return it from your fetch function and console log it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const run = async () => {  // We can't use an async function as a callback to useEffect, so we define another fn inside the callback.
      const data = await fetch_BSE_Data();
      console.log("after fetching stock_data:", data);
      makeMyNewData();
      setStockData(myNewData);
   }
   run();
}, []);
```

If you want to see the value of `stock_data` on every render, just console log it in the function body right after you define it like this:

```js
const [stock_data, setStockData] = useState([]);
console.log(stock_data); // Should log [] first render, and after the API fetches data, should show you data [...]
```

To filter your data out, you can do this

```js
const makeMyNewData = () => {

    console.log("in makeMyNewData with stock_data:", stock_data);

    const updated_stock_data = stock_data.map((item) => {
      const [first, rest, end] = item.Purpose.split("-");
      const newObject = {
        short_name: item.short_name,
        long_name: item.long_name,
        div_or_share: first,
        Ex_date: item.Ex_date,
        div_amount: isNaN(Number(end))
          ? "-"
          : "Rs. " + Number(end).toFixed(2)
      };
      return newObject;
    }); // Map function returns a new array 

    setStockData(updated_stock_data);
}
```

Comment: The `makeMyNewData` inside `useEffect` is till getting called before data is fetched and stored. As logging inside `makeMyNewData`, `stock_data` turns out to be empty.